# Moderator resignation

Tags: discussion, moderators, moderation

Effective today, I am resigning as moderator on Engineering and Software Engineering.

I find that [Robert Harvey's resignation](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9000/moderator-resignation-notice) expresses my thoughts more eloquently than what I would write, so I'll simply reference his post.

It's been an honor, and I sincerely wish the communities well.

Comment: We will all be sorry to see you go. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @hazzey!

Comment: Just read this, will miss you. Best wishes.

Comment: You have been part of this community since day one. Sorry to learn that you have left us. Best wishes.

Comment: Addendum to this: The user formerly know as GlenH7 later deleted his accounts because of this.

Comment: GlenH7 was part of this community from day one, and was instrumental shepherding engineering stackexchange. GlenH7, Thank you for your contribution.